# Regression when both the response variable and the predictor variables are boolean

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, binary-data

I have a data set where both the response variable and the predictor variables are of boolean in nature. How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

[Logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression).

> This article covers the case of a binary dependent variable—that is, where it can take only two values, "0" and "1", which represent outcomes such as pass/fail, win/lose, alive/dead or healthy/sick. ...